# JPA giving a unknown entity reference

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

My project is using JPA2/hibernate to map properties to their respective tables. As I understand it, I must put the property `mappedby` in the owner table and put `JoinColumn` in the child table(many side). I am getting the error as seen here:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an
>   unknown target entity property:
>   ninja.familyhomestay.domain.HouseImage.homestay_info in
>   ninja.familyhomestay.domain.HomestayInfo.houseImages

Here is my HomestayInfo class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "homestay_info")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "homestay_info")
data class HomestayInfo(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    var id: Long? = null,

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "homestay_info", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var houseImages: MutableSet<HouseImage> = HashSet(),
...
)
```

and my houseImage class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "house_image")
@Document(indexName = "house_image")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
class HouseImage(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    var id: Long? = null,
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "homestay_info_id")
    var homestayInfo: HomestayInfo? = null
) : Serializable
```

Any ideas? I am also using liquid to create the tables in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `HomestayInfo` class, while mentioning `@OneToMany` relationship, you are mentioning value of `mappedBy` attribute as `homestay_info`, while in `HouseImage` class there is no field with the name `homestay_info`.

You should have same field name mentioned in mappedBy and the attribute specifying the bilateral relationship in the other class.

Either rename **homestayInfo** to **homestay_Info** in the below statement :

```
var homestayInfo: HomestayInfo? = null
```

or

rename the value in `mappedBy` field to **homestayInfo**